# Can Django admin url be on a swagger file using drf-yasg?

Tags: django, django-admin, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, drf-yasg

I am deploying a Django API on Google Endpoint.
Google endpoint needs a documentatin generated with openapi2.0 to set all endpoint. If an url is not defined on the yaml file generated by openapi (here by drf-yasg) the endpoint can not be reached even if it is available.

Thing is, it would be very very very useful for me to access my django admin zone on my api but when I generate my yaml file it skips my admin url.

here is my url, basic:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # back
    path('', include('api.urls')),
    path('', include(spectacular_url)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
]
```

Do you know how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: As my SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX is set to v1 I tried to moove my admin zone url  under it but did not change anything..